# how to unzip txt.gz file and store into database using php

Tags: php, mysql, gzip, unzip, datafeed

My zip file name is Product_Catalog.txt.gz. this zip file contain one txt file.

how can i extract and store into my database

i have already done in zip file unzip and store into my database. but i can't understand .gz format. so please advise

my zip file code is here

```
if (realpath($destinationname."/".$filename)){
    if ($zip = zip_open(realpath($directory."/".$filename)))
        {
            while (($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))){
            $zipfilename=zip_entry_name($zip_entry  );
            $zipfilename."<br>";
            $tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "");
            $handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
            while($data = zip_entry_read($zip_entry,50000000000)){
            fwrite($handle,$data);
            }// end while $data
            fseek($handle,0);
            if ($separatetables);
            $table=strtok($zipfilename,"-");
            $sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$table` LIKE `cjfeeds`";
             mysql_query($sql);
```

how can i convert this code into txt.gz

Comment: You actually have two questions. First question: how to extract the contents a .gz archive using PHP. Second question: how to import a proprietary file format into a MySQL database. I suggest you ask these questions separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't extract.

```
if ($rrpath){
     if ($zip = gzopen($rrpath, "rb"))
        {   
            $filenamen = $_SESSION['files_list'][$i];       
            $zipfilename = str_replace('.gz', '', $_SESSION['files_list'][$i]); 
            $tmpfname = tempnam("/home/demoosiz/tmp", "");      
            $handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
            ini_set("max_execution_time",3000000000000);
            while($data = gzread($zip, 4096)){
            fwrite($handle,$data);
            }// end while $data
            fseek($handle,0);
            if ($separatetables);
            $table=strtok($zipfilename,"-");                   
           // $sqly = "TRUNCATE TABLE `cjfeeds`";
            //mysql_query($sqly);                           
             // I'm not too sure if this is windows specific
            $tmpfile=addslashes($tmpfname);
            //if the script times out uncomment the next line 
             ini_set("max_execution_time",3000000000000);
            $sql22 ="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$tmpfile' REPLACE  INTO TABLE `cjfeeds` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$fieldseparator' IGNORE 1 LINES;";
```

You can use this code. This code is very helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

[gzip](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip), which is generally used for single files, is not the same file format as [ZIP](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29). Although the same compression algorithm ([DEFLATE](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE)) is used in both formats, the headers are entirely different, so PHP's Zip functions will not recognize your file.

Instead, you can use the `compress.zlib://` [wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php) to open gzip-compressed files. You can then use the normal stream functions to read the file.

```
$handle = fopen("compress.zlib://$filename", 'r');
```

However, there are some limitations; for example, opening a gzipped file in read-write mode is not possible, and seeking may be slow. If necessary, you can work around these by making a temporary uncompressed copy:

```
copy("compress.zlib://$filename", $tmpfname);
```

Comment: +1. Your answer is much simpler than mine. I forgot there was a stream wrapper for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can interact with `.gz` files through the functions of the [`zlib` module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php).

---

Responding to your comment:

You won't need to do the `while($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))` since `gz` files don't hold multiple files within them. A `.gz` file is just a single file that has been compressed. Unfortunately, this also means that there is no equivalent to `zip_entry_name` either, since there is only one file.

If you're trying to read a tarball - an archive of files which have been concatenated together and gzipped to form a `.tar.gz` file - then `Zlib` isn't for you, since it's not designed to handle that. You'll want something like `PharData` instead:

```
$phar = new PharData($filename);
foreach ($phar as $phar_stream) {
  $file_data = file_get_contents($phar_stream);
  // process $file_data how you like
}
```

If these are just single-file `gz` files, then you can read the files with the gz versions of the usual filesystem functions.

You can use `gzread` to process chunks of the file the way you're currently doing with `zip_entry_read`, or you can read all lines into an array with `gzfile`. There is a `readgzfile` function which grabs the whole file, but unfortunately it seems like it just dumps the output directly to the client, rather than do a file. You could use output buffering to capture that output, but it seems like too much of a hassle considering your other options.

Comment: Hi how to change this while (($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))) to gz while. I mean this while loop is read all lines of the file and store into database. how can i change into .gz read into while

Comment: @SomethingWrong I've updated my answer to respond to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You keep calling it a zip file.  It's not a zip file (`.zip`).  It's a gzip file (`.gz`).  Different format.

You can use [`gzdecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php) to decompress a gzip file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
if(isset($_FILES['zipfile'])) 
{

    $filename = $_FILES['zipfile']['name'];
    $source = $_FILES['zipfile']['tmp_name'];
    $type = $_FILES['zipfile']['type'];

    /*$name = explode('.zip', $filename); # $name[0] returns the name of the file. $name[1] returns the extension (zip)

    ; */ # Where the file will be saved. I.E. 'extracted/myFile-02151985/'
    $target = PHYSICAL_PATH."upload/";
    // Ensures that the correct file type was chosen.
    $accepted_types = array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed');
    foreach($accepted_types as $mime_type)
    {
        if($mime_type == $type)
        {
            $okay = true;
            break;
        } 
    }

    $okay = strtolower($name[1]) == 'zip' ? true : false;

    if(!$okay) 
    {
        $msg="Please choose a zip file, dummy!";
    }
    $saved_file_location = $target.$filename;
    if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target . $filename))
    {
        global $target;
        global $unique_folder;
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
            $x = $zip->open($saved_file_location);
            if ($x === true) 
            {
                $folder=$zip->extractTo($target);
                for ( $i=0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++ ) 
                { 
                    echo $entry = $zip->getNameIndex($i); 
                    $filename=explode('/',$entry);
                    print_r($filename);
                    if($filename[1] != '')
                    { 
                        $filename_folder=$filename[0];
                        $filename = $filename[1]; //

                        $name = explode('.zip', $filename_folder); # $name[0] returns the name of the file. $name[1] returns the extension (zip)
                        //echo 'sfkdf'.$name[0];
                        $target = PHYSICAL_PATH."upload/";

                        $sql = "select `id` from `tracks` order by `id` desc";
                            $list = mysql_query($sql);
                            $list_num = mysql_num_rows($list);
                            if($list_num > 0)
                            {

                            $res = mysql_fetch_array($list);
                            $new_id=$res['id'];
                            } else {
                            $new_id=1;
                            }
                        $check_for_jpg = strpos($filename, '.mp3');

                        if ($check_for_jpg === false ){
                            echo 'Check file format.';
                            $source=$target . $name[0].'/'.$filename;
                            unlink($source);
                        } else {
                            $srch = array(' ','--','&quot;','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','_','+','{','}','|',':','"','<','>','?','[',']','\\',';',"'",',','/','*','+','~','`','=');
                            $rep = array('_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_');
                            $name_song[$i]= str_replace($srch,$rep,$filename);
                            $title_name=explode('.',$filename);

                            $new_id=$new_id+1;
                            $new_filename=$new_id.'-'.$name_song[$i];
                            mysql_query("insert into `tracks` set track='".addslashes(stripslashes($new_filename))."',title='".addslashes(stripslashes($title_name[0]))."',tape_id='".$id_last."',addDate=NOW(),status=1 ");
                            $source=$target . $name[0].'/'.$filename; $target_move=$target.$new_filename;
                            if(rename($source,$target_move)) { unlink($source); } else { echo 'not';}
                            echo 'folder zip';
                            echo '<li>' . $new_filename . '</li>';
                        }
                        rmdir($target . $name[0]);
                    }
                    else { echo $target = PHYSICAL_PATH."upload/";
                        $sql = "select `id` from `test_table` order by `id` desc";

                        $list = mysql_query($sql);
                        $list_num = mysql_num_rows($list);
                        if($list_num > 0) {
                        //and, instead of using "while":
                        $res = mysql_fetch_array($list); // will return the highest "id" number
                        echo $new_id=$res['id'];
                        } else {
                        $new_id=1;
                        }

                        $check_for_jpg = strpos($entry, '.mp3');

                        if ($check_for_jpg === false ){
                            echo 'Check file format.';
                            $source=$target .$entry;
                            unlink($source);
                        } else {
                            $srch = array(' ','--','&quot;','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','_','+','{','}','|',':','"','<','>','?','[',']','\\',';',"'",',','/','*','+','~','`','=');
                            $rep = array('_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_');
                            $name_song[$i]= str_replace($srch,$rep,$entry);
                            $title_name=explode('.',$entry);
                            $new_id=$new_id+1;
                            $new_filename=$new_id.'-'.$name_song[$i];
                            mysql_query("insert into `tracks` set track='".addslashes(stripslashes($new_filename))."',title='".addslashes(stripslashes($title_name[0]))."',tape_id='".$id_last."',status=1 ");
                            $source=$target .$entry; $target_move=$target.$new_filename;
                            if(rename($source,$target_move)) { unlink($source); } else { echo 'not';}
                            echo 'only zip';
                            echo '<li>' . $new_filename . '</li>';
                        }

                    }
                }
                $zip->close();
                unlink($saved_file_location); #deletes the zip file. We no longer need it.
            } else {
                die("There was a problem. Please try again!");
            }

    } else {
        $msg="There was a problem";
    }
}
```